# Add tap gesture recognizer from another file

Tags: swift, delegates, uitapgesturerecognizer

Currently I have 2 classes: ViewController and class A. My objective is to add tap gesture recognizer to a UIView from class A. My ViewController:

```
class ViewController {
    @IBOutlet var area: UIView!

    func enterClassA() {
        let classA = A(self.area)
        //some processing
    }
}

class A : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    private var currView: UIView!

    init(newView: UIView) {
        self.currView = newView
        self.addTapGesture()
    }

    func addTapGesture() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.currView, action:#selector(tapDetected(_:)))
        tap.delegate = self.currView as! UIGestureRecognizerdelegate? //***
        self.currView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func tapDetected(_ tapGesture: UIGesturerecognizer) {
        print ("Tap detected!")
    }
}
```

But now it's giving error: could not cast value of type 'UIView' to "UIGestureRecognizerDelegate". I tried modifying line *** to

```
tap.delegate = self
```

But it's still not working, showing error: unrecognized selector sent to instance. Deleting the line gives the same error. May I know if this is even doable or not (adding gesture recognizer from a different class)? If so then how should I approach it?

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.currView, action:#selector(tapDetected(_:)))
```

You say the gesture recognizer to search the `tapDetected()` function in the `self.currView` object. Try to change the target:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(tapDetected(_:)))
```

And yes, it should be like that:

```
tap.delegate = self
```

Since your `A` class conforms to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.